# IE11 - Cient side redirect to jsp unable to assess session attribute

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer, httpsession, window.location

My login ajax call is like this

```
        $.get("LoginServlet", {'agileid': id, 'passwd': passwd, 'remember': 'yes' }, function(data) {
        var results = JSON.parse(data);
        if ( results.status == "failed") alert(data);
        else window.location.href = 'Main.jsp'; 
    });
```

My LoginServlet will set a session attribute special object which cannot be saved on the client side.

In Main.jsp, will determine existence of the session object and perform the necessary actions.

```
<%@page import="agile.px.myagiledashboard.listeners.SessionResourcesObject"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" session="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
HttpSession hSession = request.getSession();
System.out.println("Main.jsp: " + hSession.getId()); //This is to make sure the session is the same as in LoginServlet request
SessionResourcesObject SRO = (SessionResourcesObject)    hSession.getAttribute("SRO");
String userName = "";

if ( SRO != null) {
try {
    userName = SRO.getCUser();
    System.out.println("main.jsp: " + userName);
} catch (Exception e) {

}

}

%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
....
```

The code works with Chrome but when run in IE11 (in compatibility mode - company IT policy - can't change), the session object is always null after redirected to the jsp page.

Anyone one has the same problem? Or can anyone point out the problem(s) in my code and to fix this?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: I figured it out now; it's due to IE's behaviour. A new session is created when LoginServlet is created and in IE casued another new session  to be created (somehow) when window.locations.href is used to re-direct from client side. My question is now how to do client side redirect without a new session in IE11.

Comment: Did you try to use any alternative redirect methods? If not, you can have a test with Window.location or Window.location.assign or Window.location.replace or self.location to check whether it helps to avoid the issue in IE or not.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  'replace' definitely will cause  a new session but except for location.href what are the options for client side redirect. Server side redirect is out of question in this case.  Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what understanding you have for client side redirect. all Javascript redirects considered as client side redirect. Ref: https://audisto.com/insights/guides/31/#client-side-redirects-7a55aa658f46558eb85223dfb0ab97f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange enough: Using location.href solved the problem. Chrome does not behave differently , but in IE11 location.href will not create a new session but window.location.href will.